# Know which Div is within the viewportHeight (and how much)

Tags: jquery, scrollview, jquery-waypoints

I have a large vertically scrolling with DIVs stacked on top of other DIVs. I am trying to figure out which DIV the user is looking at currently. I managed to do this fairly well using waypoints, but I allow the user to load more content within the DIVs (which makes them taller) and seems to screw up the waypoints.

Here is what my waypoints code looks like, I have one of these for each of the DIVs:

```
$(function() {

var $things = $('#infoWrapper');

$things.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    //do stuff
  }
}, { offset: function() {
    return $(this).height()-($.waypoints('viewportHeight') / 3);
  }
});

$things.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    //do stuff
  }
}, {
  offset: function() {
    return -$(this).height()+($.waypoints('viewportHeight') / 1.2);
  }
});

});
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this; perhaps testing the DIVs to see which DIV has the highest percentage of the viewportHeight (so if the user scrolls so that DIV1 has 20% and DIV2 has 40% then run the DIV2 code etc).

What is the best way to know which DIV (of an unknown height) is being currently being viewed?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you check out this [jQuery-Visible plugin](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/) which is made exactly for that. It allows us to quickly check if an element is within the browsers visual viewport, regardless of the scroll position. If a user can see this element, the function will return true. From there you can determine which is occupying the larger part of the viewport - which should be simple math. This way you only test the items that are actually visible.

Comment: Can I measure if it is in the viewport without waypoints then?

Comment: I can't seem to get their plugin to work. I just get 'false'. I am simply using:

Comment: I have tried it and I can't seem to get it work. I am just using simple code copied from their example (more or less):

    `var detectPartial = $('#detect_type').val() == 'partial';
    var isVisible = $('#work').visible( detectPartial );
    alert(isVisible);`
 
I just get false no matter where I am on the screen.

Comment: From I understand from the documentation you're supposed to do it like this: `var isVisible = $('#work').visible();`. That will return true if the entire element is on screen. Doing this: `$('#work').list( true );` will return true if any part is visible.

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle with your code. That should make it easier to help you out.

Comment: Ya, that is what it says, but `$('#work').list(true);` returns an error. Sounds easy when you read the documentation, but that simple line of code returns an error of "not a function". I don't know what a jsFiddle is :)

Comment: Google jsFiddle and you'll find out. It's basically a place where you can make a mini code base for testing and sharing. I will need it to have all the related code so I can continue to help you.

Comment: I had a look, but by the time I figure out how to get my code into there I can likely figure out a different solution. I can shoot you my email addy with URL if you like? But really the code is quite simple, but I suppose you are correct that something else could be messing with the intent.

Comment: I have it working good. I manually calculated the scroll location vs the DIV and then used that to decide which DIV was the closest to the scroll location. Maybe not as tidy as your suggestion, but it only too 12 lines of code with no plugins (yours or waypoints). Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working, cus that's what's important.